# How can I get cardslib into eclipse

Tags: android, libraries, cardslib

hope someone knows better.

Since hours I try to include the cardslib - https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib, unfortunately without success.
When I want to including as it's described in the https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#reference-this-project-as-a-library-in-eclipse.
When I want to load the lib into the workspace the Error "An internal error occurred during: "Adjusting Android Project Classpath".
Source attachment path 'C:\Users\User\android-sdks\sources\android-14' for IClasspathEntry must be absolute" appears.
I never had such an error before. What causes it?
After pressing "OK" the lib gets into the workspace and "cardslib] Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 14" is shown on the console. So the lib is marked with an error.
After getting through the document (mark as lib etc. in properties) I still get some errors:

The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
BuildConfig.java    /cardslib/gen/it/gmariotti/cardslib/library/cards   line 1  Java Problem

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.
styles.xml  /cardslib/res/values    line 23 Android AAPT Problem

The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project    cardslib        Unknown Java Problem

I asked google about it already but didn't find a match so I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added cardsLib in Propertis>Android>add ?

Comment: No but I marked "is Library" - in the Properties of cardslib itself.

Comment: is Library is to tell eclipse that the following project is a library project. May be you need to add that cardsLib library project to your main project

Comment: Unfortunately no changes after via Properties>Android>add...trying :(

Comment: Open the library project properties on page Android and make sure at least Android 4.4 is selected as compile SDK.

Comment: Did you imported your library project in eclipse. if you have added library project successfully you may see your library project custom view in graphical layout palette in custom & library views

Comment: It's Android 5.0.1 under properties. I can see the lib-project in the Package-Explorer

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong

Comment: You have to compile with api21 the library. And it is time to switch to Android Studio and gradle.

Comment: I have checked that build target is API 21 and tried via "build project" but I still got the errors.